# column sort in javascript with repeated columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I need a javascript table sorter that can deal with repeated columns.  the table is laid out in multi-columns, because it is so narrow.  for example:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr> <th>name</th> <th>score</th>  <th>name</th> <th>score</th> </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr> <td> n1 </td> <td> 4 </td>    <td> n3 </td> <td> 2 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> n2 </td> <td> 3 </td>    <td> n4 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the table to sort on scores across both score columns when one of the score headers is clicked.  same for names, of course.  in my real applications, I may have 100 rows, each only a few characters (2 columns) wide, and the reorganized table may well be only 20 rows (=> 10 columns), and thus be more easily viewable.

(actually, what I would really want is an html table that can automatically widen itself by splitting long and narrow tables into wide and short tables, but this is too much to ask for.  I do not believe this exists.)

does a js (better yet, jquery) tablesorter with such abilities exist?

/iaw

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Please post the plain HTML.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "an html table that can automatically widen itself by splitting long and narrow tables into wide and short tables"?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I reckon what you are looking for the tablesorter plugin to sort the column and **see working demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/f9VvL/

In the given example you can click on the scores and you can see the sorting happening.

If you keen: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

for styling you can use css awesomness to do that;

Hope this helsp the cause `:)`

**script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>


  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>


  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css">
```

**code**

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    // *** Appearance ***
    // fix the column widths
    widthFixed: false,
    // include zebra and any other widgets
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    // other options: "ddmmyyyy" & "yyyymmdd"
    dateFormat: "mmddyyyy",

    // *** Functionality ***
    // starting sort direction "asc" or "desc"
    sortInitialOrder: "asc",
    // These are detected by default,
    // but you can change or disable them
    headers: {
        // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
        0: { sorter: "text" },
        1: { sorter: "digit" },
        2: { sorter: "text" },
        3: { sorter: "url" }
    },
    // extract text from the table - this is how is
    // it done by default
    textExtraction: {
        0: function(node) {
            return $(node).text();
        },
        1: function(node) {
            return $(node).text();
        }
    },
    // forces the user to have this/these column(s) sorted first
    sortForce: null,
    // initial sort order of the columns
    // [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ]
    sortList: [],
    // default sort that is added to the end of the users sort
    // selection.
    sortAppend: null,
    // Use built-in javascript sort - may be faster, but does not
    // sort alphanumerically
    sortLocaleCompare: false,
    // Setting this option to true will allow you to click on the
    // table header a third time to reset the sort direction.
    sortReset: false,
    // Setting this option to true will start the sort with the
    // sortInitialOrder when clicking on a previously unsorted column.
    sortRestart: false,
    // The key used to select more than one column for multi-column
    // sorting.
    sortMultiSortKey: "shiftKey",

    // *** Customize header ***
    onRenderHeader: function() {
        // the span wrapper is added by default
        $(this).find('span').addClass('roundedCorners');
    },
    // jQuery selectors used to find the header cells.
    selectorHeaders: 'thead th',

    // *** css classes to use ***
    cssAsc: "headerSortUp",
    cssChildRow: "expand-child",
    cssDesc: "headerSortDown",
    cssHeader: "header",
    tableClass: 'tablesorter',

    // *** widget css class settings ***
    // column classes applied, and defined in the skin
    widgetColumns: {
        css: ["primary", "secondary", "tertiary"]
    },
    // find these jQuery UI class names by hovering over the
    // Framework icons on this page:
    // http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
    widgetUitheme: {
        css: [
            "ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s", // Unsorted icon
            "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s", // Sort up (down arrow)
            "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" // Sort down (up arrow)
        ]
    },
    // 
    widgetZebra: {
        css: ["even", "odd"]
    },

    // *** prevent text selection in header ***
    cancelSelection: true,

    // *** send messages to console ***
    debug: false

}).tablesorterPager({

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
    container: $(".pager"),

    // use this format: "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}"
    // where {page} is replaced by the page number and {size} is replaced
    // by the number of records to show
    ajaxUrl: null,

    // process ajax so that the data object is returned along with
    // the total number of rows
    ajaxProcessing: function(ajax) {
        if (ajax && ajax.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
            // example ajax:
            // {
            //   "data" : [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Foo", "Last": "Bar" }],
            //   "total_rows" : 100
            // }
            // return [ "data", "total_rows" ];
            return [ajax.data, ajax.total_rows];
        }
    },

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
    // possible variables:
    // {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
    output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',

    // apply disabled classname to the pager arrows when the rows at
    // either extreme is visible - default is true
    updateArrows: true,

    // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
    page: 0,

    // Number of visible rows - default is 10
    size: 10,

    // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter
    // how many records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty
    // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
    fixedHeight: false,

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed
    // if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
    removeRows: false,

    // css class names of pager arrows
    cssNext: '.next',
    // next page arrow
    cssPrev: '.prev',
    // previous page arrow
    cssFirst: '.first',
    // go to first page arrow
    cssLast: '.last',
    // go to last page arrow
    cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
    // location of the "output"
    cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
    // dropdown that sets the "size" option
    // class added to arrows when at the extremes 
    // (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
    // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
    cssDisabled: 'disabled'

});​
```